# Printing an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist, printing

I am trying to print out an array list in java.

Right now my output is -

```
Account number: 22, Company Name: , Seed Money: 250000.0, Return On Investment: 0.03, Term Length: 6
```

I would like it to output in a list format such as

```
account number: 22
company name: test
```

and so on

Right now my code for the print statement is -

```
for(int c = 0; c < venturePrograms.size(); c++) {
    System.out.println(venturePrograms.get(c));
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @khelwood Luckily for me it says "possible" and not just "duplicate". :)

Comment: That's not your Lists fault, the `toString()` implementation of your model class is at fault.

Comment: You're using `println()`. You're showing output with a single line. Either you have one item in your list, or that's not your output.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Tom is right. I don't know what the generic type of `venturePrograms` is, but all you have to do is override it's `toString` method.